# how to select the string before the first occurrence of a character using regexp in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have string like below

```
ThisSentence.should.split.beforeFirstPeriod.ofTheSentence
```

I want to select `ThisSentence`.

How can I do it with `regexp_substr()`?

Comment: What exactly you want to extract? first string before comma?

Answer (score 5):

Simple `SUBSTR()` and `INSTR()` can do the same job:

```
SUBSTR(YourString, 0, INSTR(YourString, '.')-1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Sagi's answer is correct.  However, Oracle also offers `regexp_substr()` which provides more general functionality:

```
select regexp_substr(str, '[^.]+', 1, 1)
```

Comment: MT0's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36012317/270794 worked better, for when there were no spaces.